# Topology - Is infinite product of quotient maps a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology

Product of two quotient maps need not be a quotient map.
However,

given two quotient maps $$p : A → B\\ q : C → D$$

if  A, B, C, D are locally compact Housdorff then $$p × q : A × C → B × D$$
is a quotient map.

Does this still hold for product of arbitrary number of maps?

Given collection of quotient maps $\{p_i : X_i → Y_i | i ∈ I\}$, where $X_i, Y_i$ are locally compact Housdorff spaces for all $i∈I$,
is $$\prod p_i : \prod X_i → \prod Y_i$$ a quotient map in the usual product topology?

I first attempted to find a counterexample in $\Bbb R^\omega$, trying to figure out whether $p × id^\omega : \Bbb R × \Bbb R^\omega → p(\Bbb R)\Bbb × R^\omega$ is quotient if p is any quotient map with such condition.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your product need not be locally compact, I don’t know if that troubles you at all though.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, I do think there might be a way to exploit that fact to disprove the main statement.. But I can't make any further progress.